# net core 2.0 appsettings.json save on bin directory

Tags: json, .net-core, connection-string

I am new in `net core 2.0`.

I am connecting to datbase. I am used to use an `App.Config` or `Web.Config` to set the connection string. But in net core 2.0 uses `appsettings.json` file instead.

When I compile de Application, `appsettings.json` file is not generated in `bin` directory. So when I run the appplication from Console `c>dotnet prj.dll` thrown an excepción because connection file is not found.

My question is... I have to copy `appsettings.json` file manually  to `bin` directory or is there a way to save it in `bin` directory when Project is compiled?

thanks

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39749344/copying-files-on-compile-for-asp-net-core-1-0-project and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38178340/how-can-i-ensure-that-appsettings-dev-json-gets-copied-to-the-output-folder

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've been looking for an answer to this question and most of the posts I've found reference the project.json file which has now been deprecated in favour of the .csproj file [according to this guide published March 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj).

This document also indicates [how you can use the "CopyToOutputDirectory" attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj#files) in your .csproj file to ensure your appsettings.json file is copied to the output directory on build:

```
<Project ...>
    ...
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="appsettings.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

.

Comment: Also, if you use Visual Studio and don’t want to edit .csproj file manually you can “Right click” appsettings.json file and choose “Properties”. In “Advanced” find “Copy to Output Directory” and choose “Copy always”.