# What is the difference between "none include" and "none update" in SDK-style csproj projects?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, msbuild, csproj

I was looking for the correct way to ensure appsettings.json is copied to the bin directory when building my project.

[This article](https://dev.to/jeikabu/microservice-based-application-with-aspnet-core-generic-host-cel) recommends using "none update"

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49543365/453441) recommends using "none include":

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="appsettings.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
</ItemGroup>
```

What is the difference between `update` and `include`?

Answer (score 14):

> What is the difference between update and include?

According to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/item-element-msbuild?view=vs-2019):

**Usage**:

`Include` attribute => The file or wildcard to include in the list of items.

`Update` attribute => Enables you to modify metadata of a file that was included by using a glob.

**Working Scope:**

`Include attribute`:

1.Works for both `normal .net framewrok`(non-sdk format), `.net core and .net standard`(sdk format), also C++ projects...

2.Used in many VS versions(As I know, from VS2010 to VS2019)

3.`Include` works even in ItemGroup in [Targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-targets?view=vs-2019)

`Update attribute`:

1.Works for .net core projects

2.Available in VS2017 and later

3.Not supported when using it in an ItemGroup inside a Target

**Tests and results:**

First Test when c.txt is not included:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <DoSth Include="a.txt"/>
    <DoSth Include="b.txt"/>
    <DoSth Update="c.txt" Metadata="test"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="MyTest" AfterTargets="build">
    <Message Text="@(DoSth)" Importance="high"/>
  </Target>
  <!--The output is a.txt and b.txt, no c.txt.-->
```

Second Test when c.txt is included:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <DoSth Include="a.txt"/>
    <DoSth Include="b.txt"/>
    <DoSth Include="c.txt" Metadata="original"/>
    <DoSth Update="c.txt" Metadata="test"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="MyTest" AfterTargets="build">
    <Message Text="@(DoSth)" Importance="high"/> <!--The output files are a.txt,b.txt and c.txt.-->
    <Message Text="%(DoSth.Identity)+%(DoSth.Metadata)" Importance="high"/>  <!--The output Metadata of c.txt is test instead of original-->
  </Target>
```

So it's obvious that `Update attribute` is only used to **update** one Item's metadata. It has no function to include some files. And it will only work when one file **has been Included** in one Item.

> To clarify something when using `Update + appsettings.json` in `.net core` console and
>   `asp.net core` web app:

**In Asp.net core web application:**

If you create a new `asp.net core web` project, you can see the `appsettings.json` file in Solution Explorer by default.But if you read the `xx.csproj` you can't find the definition there, the definitions is not explicitly shown in `xx.csproj` for sdk-format.

In this situation, if we use script like `<None Include="appsettings.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />`, it always works to copy that file to output.

But for script `<None Update="appsettings.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />`, it works only when there's no statement like `<Content xxx="appsettings.json"...>` in the project file.

And I recommend you do this by VS UI instead manual editing xx.csproj. We can change the `Build Action and Copy To Output` Settings in `Property Window`:

[image]

If we set the `build action` to be `None`, and Copy to Output to be `Copy if Never` of `Copy Always`, in xx.csproj we can find:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="appsettings.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

So VS use None+Include behind for this. According to all above, I suggest you use `None+Include` instead of `None+Update` in your project. Also, the most recommended way is to control the copy behavior by UI in VS IDE instead of manual editing. Hope all above helps :)

**Update1:**

We can add this script in project file to output the info about None Items and Content Items that not shown in csproj:

```
  <Target Name="TrytoFindDefinitionsNowShown" AfterTargets="build">
    <Message Text="None: @(None)" Importance="high"/>
    <Message Text="Content: @(Content)" Importance="high"/>
  </Target>
```

**Update2:**

I just did some tests and find even in .net core console project in VS, though no definitions in csproj, the update can work. Strange?

And finally I found this is because that definition is **hidden or not shown** in csproj file, actually when you have a appsettings.json file in project, you've already have a `<None Include="appsettings.json"...` defined(sometimes Content+include, ikt depends on the way you add that file), though that's not valid to see in csproj, see my screenshot:

[image]

So that's why Update can work for the copy behavior though it's something used to modify metadata. Before we use the Update, there already exists the definition `None+Include+Appsettings.json` though that's not shown in csproj. (For sdk format)

**Update3:**

I did some little changes to script in Update1 to display the `<None Include="appsettings.json">`'s metadata.

[image]

So in a .net core console project, `appsettings.json` file by default is

```
<None Include="appsettings.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="Never" />
```

That's why both `None+Include+Always`(Overwrite) and `None+Update+Always or PreserveNewest`(Modify the metadata) work for copy behavior. And it can describe why by default that file won't be copied even VS have hidden `None+Include` definitions somewhere. Because the `CopyToOutputDirectory` is set to be Never by default.

Comment: You said that `update Enables you to modify metadata of a file that was included by using a glob.` When I used the update snippet, I confirmed that the appsettings.json was being copied over to the output folder when it wasn't there before. I also confirmed that if the contents change in the source appsettings.json, the copy in the bin directory is updated after a build. So it seems it isn't just for updating metadata?

Comment: @user453441 For `when it wasn't there before`? Do you test it in asp.net core project? Please see my statement about `In Asp.net core web application`. Those definitions are hidden and not explicitly shown in xx.csproj for sdk-format. Compare the content of project file from an empty .net framework console and an empty .net core console, you can see the difference. The new SDK-Format is a much more clear way.

Comment: No I am using a .net core console application (target framework netcoreapp3.0), and I am using VS code.

Comment: @user453441 I guess the Update2 can help to resolve your puzzle and confirm the usage of Update. Though the definition is not shown in csproj, we can use target+message task to output the hidden definitions. Hope it helps :)

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm having a hard time reading your answer, or even just the Update2 section by itself. If I already have a `none include` or a `content include` that is "hidden or not shown", doesn't that mean the appsettings.json will be copied over to the output folder even if I don't add my `none update`?? I upvoted your answer because I appreciate your help researching the problem.

Comment: @user453441 Hmm, my fault :( Actually I should add more details to describe `If I already have a none include or a content include that is "hidden or not shown", doesn't that mean the appsettings.json will be copied over to the output folder even if I don't add my none update??` . I will update the answer sooner to clarify it and help if someone has similar puzzle :)

Comment: Perhaps Update3 can resolve your puzzle in last comment... You can try the script in Update3(do a little change to script in Update1) to output the hidden definitions of your appsettings.json file. May it helps :-(

Comment: While I can appreciate the effort you put in this answer, I still don't quite understand the difference. What does it mean to "modify metadata"? What metadata?

Answer (score 1):

**Summary:** In SDK-style projects, there's a good chance the files you would include are already included in the project by the default rules.  If so, `<None Include=...>` is a bit redundant (albeit harmless), so you may choose to prefer `<None Update=...>`.

---

As documented in [this table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/item-element-msbuild#attributes), the update attribute is available "only for .NET Core projects in Visual Studio 2017 or later".  This means it is used in [SDK-style projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview).

In SDK-style projects, some files are [included by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview#default-includes-and-excludes) as Compile, EmbeddedResource, or None items. Basically, files in your project folder and its subfolders are Compile items if they have a language extension like .cs, are EmbeddedResource items if they are .resx, and are None items for almost all other cases (excluding a few things like .*proj and .sln files).

Since these files are already included in the project, there's no need to explicitly include them with `<None Include=...>`.  If you want to add some additional metadata like `CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest"`, it suffices to use `<None Update=...>`

That said, `<None Include=...>` will still also work perfectly well, it's just a bit redundant because it's including a file which was already included.  If pressed to give a recommendation, I'd say use `Update` except where `Include` is actually needed, but generally it shouldn't matter much.

Note however that if you set either the [EnableDefaultItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#enabledefaultitems) or [EnableDefaultNoneItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#enabledefaultnoneitems) build properties to `false` then you will actually need to use `<None Include=...>` to add your items.  (Both properties are `true` by default.)