# iOS App properly save user credentials in file / appmemory

Tags: c#, visual-studio, authentication, xamarin, xamarin.ios

**Context:**

I am working on an app which makes database and API calls. Therefore, for each API call, I need to send the API-Key within the request as Authentication. Also, I have multiple APIs which are called, so currently I use a `credentials.json` file which contains the credentials and it's located inside the project, right next to my classes and interfaces. This works fine on a Console-Application on Windows.

**The problems that occur:**

When I implement the Library with this Logic in a Xamarin iOS App, i get a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file/Users/myname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/....`

**My Questions:**

1. Why cant the app running on iOS not find the file?
2. How can I make my `credentials.json` accessible for every device I deploy on?
3. Which would be the *proper* way to do this?

The code where I access the file:  `var credPath = Path.Combine(  Directory.GetParent(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.Parent.FullName,"MyDLL/creds.json");`

Comment: you have to actually post the relevant code if you expect us to help you find an error in it

Comment: I hope you don't store sensitive info on your `credentials.json` file, anyway, you could _deploy_ the json file when building if you indicate it on your csproj file, see [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48708965/net-core-2-0-appsettings-json-save-on-bin-directory)